# tengo un problema sobre string format c# tengo mi codigo con mas de 12 digitos y el excel se muestra asi 2.34234E+17

Tags: c#, .net

**VISTA**

```
<table id="t01">
    @{
        if (ViewBag.TipoReporte == 1)
        {
            <tr align="center" valign="middle">
                <th colspan="10"><h1>STOCK GENERAL</h1></th>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center" valign="middle">
                <th colspan="10"><h1>A LA FECHA  @ViewBag.fecha</h1></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Material</th>
                <th>Rubro</th>
                <th>UM</th>
                <th>Ingresos</th>
                <th>Salidas</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>Costo</th>
                <th>Valorizado</th>
            </tr>
            foreach (var item in ViewBag.DatosExcel)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.TipoAlmacen</td>
                    <td>@String.Format(item.codigo_interno.ToString())</td>
                    <td>@item.descripcion_material</td>
                    <td>@item.rubro</td>
                    <td>@item.unidadmaterial</td>
                    <td align="right">@String.Format("{0:0.00}", item.ingreso).Replace(",", ".")</td>
                    <td align="right">@String.Format("{0:0.00}", item.salida).Replace(",", ".")</td>
                    <td align="right">@String.Format("{0:0.00}", item.stock).Replace(",", ".")</td>
                    <td align="right">@String.Format("{0:0.00}", item.costo).Replace(",", ".")</td>
                    <td align="right">@String.Format("{0:0.00}", item.valorizado).Replace(",", ".")</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
</table>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult ExportarExcelStockAlmacen(string fecha, int Local = 0, int Almacen = 0, int LocalAlmacen = 0, int TipoReporte = 0)
        {

            ReportesAD oReportesAD = new ReportesAD();
            ReporteStockAlmacen record = new ReporteStockAlmacen();

            record.local = Convert.ToInt32(Local);
            record.almacen = Convert.ToInt32(Almacen);
            record.fechaEmisionDoc_GuiasCab = Convert.ToString(fecha);
            record.usuario = Convert.ToInt32(((Sesion)Session["Session_Usuario_Acceso"]).usuario.id_Usuario);
            //record.fechaemision = Convert.ToInt32(fecha);

            // por stock general
            if (TipoReporte == 1)
            {
                record.tiporeporte = Convert.ToInt32(1);
                ViewBag.DatosExcel = oReportesAD.BuscarPorStockGeneral(record);
            }
            // por stock almacen
            else if (TipoReporte == 3)
            {
                record.tiporeporte = Convert.ToInt32(2);
                ViewBag.DatosExcel = oReportesAD.BuscarPorStockAlmacenGeneral(record);
            }
            // Stock General detallado por Movimientos
            else if (TipoReporte == 2)
            {
                record.tiporeporte = Convert.ToInt32(1);
                ViewBag.DatosExcel = oReportesAD.BuscarPorStockGeneralMovimientos(record);
            }
            // Movimientos o Stock por Almacen por Movimientos
            else if (TipoReporte == 4)
            {
                record.tiporeporte = Convert.ToInt32(2);
                ViewBag.DatosExcel = oReportesAD.BuscarPorStockAlmacenMovimientos(record);
            }

            string archivo = "ReporteExcel_Almacen_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") + ".xls";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + archivo);
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

            ViewBag.TipoReporte = TipoReporte;
            ViewBag.fecha = fecha;
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Naxin: así como está, la pregunta es bastante complicada de abordar. Dale a [edit] para poner un título descriptivo, un texto explicativo y una parte relevante de código para que podamos reproducir el error.

Comment: No está muy clara la pregunta. Una cosa es mostrar un dato en tu página y otra diferente al exportar a excel. Tu problema no parece estar en el `String.Format`, si no en el código que usas para exportar los datos a excel.

Comment: Si el problema es al mostrar tus datos en la pagina, prueba esta linea: `<td>@String.Format(item.codigo_interno.ToString("D"))</td>`

Comment: Sería útil que incluyeras un [mcve], énfasis en la palabra *mínimo*.

Comment: El problema no es de tu código, por alguna razón en Excel se muestran así los números, selecciona la columna, da clic en el combo de selección de Formato y selecciona número, ahí ya decide si ponerle o quitarle los decimales que te genere

Comment: pero eso es una incomodidad para el cliente no crees tu

Comment: Pero, programáticamente ahí no puedes hacer nada al respecto.

Comment: Me quedé pensando en esta pregunta, y la única opción que se me ocurre es que al inicio de cada número, pongas un apostrofe `'`, aunque, en el Excel se va a mostrar todo el número no podrás hacer operaciones y/o cáclulos, lo cual también requiere intervención del usuario que utiliza el archivo de Excel

Comment: gracias por tu comentario pero ese archivo lo utilizo luego para lo importen en otro sistema y hacer eso es darle mas trabajo al cliente

Comment: @NaxinIA, ya que no usas `Microsoft.Office.Interop`, mi sugerencia es: _busca cómo autoajustar el tamaño de las columnas_. En interop se usa algo como: `mySheet.Columns.AutoFit();`.

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es el codigo, el numero es demasiado grande para que entre dentro de la casilla del excel, al ampliar la casilla el numero aparecera perfectamente.
Podrias ampliar la casilla mediante css, podria funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Excel tiene ese comportamiento por default. Si lo que quieres es mostrar una clave (por ejemplo, ya que no entiendo en cuál dato es el problema) entonces desde el código no lo trates como número, sino como `string` (y en tu base de datos como `char(12)` si es una cantidad fija de caracteres o como `varchar` si no lo es..

Adicionalmente, si quieres evitar ese comportamiento de Excel con los números, ponle una comilla simple al inicio del texto y te lo reconocerá como tal:

```
foreach (var item in ViewBag.DatosExcel)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.TipoAlmacen</td>
        <td>'@item.codigo_interno</td> @* Suponiendo que debe ser aquí *@
        <td>@item.descripcion_material</td>
        <td>@item.rubro</td>
        <td>@item.unidadmaterial</td>
        <td align="right">@String.Format("'{0:0.00}", item.ingreso).Replace(",", ".")</td> @* Suponiendo que deba ir aquí *@
        <td align="right">@String.Format("{0:0.00}", item.salida).Replace(",", ".")</td>
        <td align="right">@String.Format("{0:0.00}", item.stock).Replace(",", ".")</td>
        <td align="right">@String.Format("{0:0.00}", item.costo).Replace(",", ".")</td>
        <td align="right">@String.Format("{0:0.00}", item.valorizado).Replace(",", ".")</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Toma en cuenta que esto los mostrará como texto, así que olvídate de las operaciones aritméticas.